# Counterparty sent session rejection message at unexpected time with message Unable to establish session

Tags: database, state, h2, default, corda

My question is that when I create the second state, Corda throws a exception. And here is exception: "message": "**net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Counterparty sent session rejection message at unexpected time with message Unable to establish session**". But the **first state** can store in Corda's **default database**.

So it is weird.

```
first state:[
  {
    "foud_name": "23",
    "financing_name":"23",
    "financing_project":"23",
    "company_name":"23",
    "data_producer":"23",
    "attachment_name":"23",
    "attachment_type":"23",
    "attachment_id":"23"
  }
]
```

When I store the second , It throws an exception:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-08-24T09:47:02.654+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Counterparty sent session rejection message at unexpected time with message Unable to establish session",
  "path": "/api/v1/resarch-attachment"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message indicates that:

- As part of a flow, you are sending a message to a counterparty
- The counterparty has a response flow registered to respond to the flow that is sending the message, but it doesn't expect to receive a message at this time

There are several reasons this could happen. The response flow may already have ended, or it may not be expecting to receive a message at this time.

You say that the error message only happens the second time. With the details I have, I'd hypothesise that your initiating flow is trying to make the counterparty to invoke the response flow multiple times. Something like:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class InitiatorFlow(val counterparty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val counterpartySession = initiateFlow(counterparty)

        (0..99).forEach { 
            counterpartySession.send("My payload.")
        }
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(InitiatorFlow::class)
class ResponderFlow(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        counterpartySession.receive<String>()
    }
}
```

This will not work. When you start an initiating flow, it is given a flow ID. This ID is used when communicating with counterparties to tell them which response flow to use:

- If the counterparty has never received a message from a flow with this ID, it will create a new instance of the response flow
- If the counterparty has received a message from a flow with this ID before, it will continue using this instance

  - If this flow instance has finished running, it will not create a new instance, but assume there has been a mistake, giving the error message you see above

Instead, you'd need to use subflows to create a new flow ID for each communication with the counterparty. Something like:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class InitiatorFlow(val counterparty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        (0..99).forEach {
            subFlow(SendMessageFlow(counterparty))
        }
    }
}

@InitiatingFlow
class SendMessageFlow(val counterparty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val counterpartySession = initiateFlow(counterparty)
        counterpartySession.send("My payload.")
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(SendMessageFlow::class)
class ResponderFlow(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        counterpartySession.receive<String>()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this message first time. I have correctly configured responder and initiator. Am I missing something?